# Is 'u' the same as 'you'?

Tags: slang, abbreviations

I saw this sentence while I was using HiNative:

> hey ，could u pronounce (a sentence) for me?

'U' is pronounced like 'you'. Is 'u' the same as 'you'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two forms, "u" and "you" may have the same meanings but otherwise they have very different registers, and usages. Learners should avoid writing; "u", "b4", or "2nite", etc.  in any formal correspondence if they wish to create a positive impression in their readers. In texts, IMs (instant messaging)  and emails to friends these **abbreviations**, also known as *textese*, *txt-speak*, and *texting language*  are more than acceptable and can save the writer time and space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the same, just like when people use "*r*" instead of "*are*," though I would stray away doing that.